# Does a relation on a set that partitions it an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I know that if a relation is an equivalence relation on a set, it partitions the set. However, I do not know whether the inverse is also true. Namely, if a relation partitions a set, is it an equivalence relation on the set?

Comment: What's the definition of a (non-equivalence) relation partitioning the set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's true. If $A$ is a set and $\mathcal A=\{A_i~:~i\in I\}$ is a partition of $A$ with an arbitrary index set $I$, then you can define $\sim$ by
$$
x\sim y :\Leftrightarrow \exists i\in I : x,y\in A_i.
$$
You can check that this defines an equivalence relation.